# Getting error Cannot use import statement outside a module when using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

Hello i am running Ubuntu server on "digitalocean" but getting error when trying to run my app using `pm2 start App.js` at first it shows as its online but ones you `pm2 list` its says errored and in the logs you can see error
`/var/www/project/src/index.js:1 0|src      | import React from 'react'; 0|src      | ^^^^^^ 0|src      | 0|src      | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module 0|src      |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16) 0|src      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27) 0|src      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) 0|src      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) 0|src      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) 0|src      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23) 0|src      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) 0|src      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) 0|src      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) 0|src      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)`

Comment: add "type": "module" in your package.json

Comment: It removed `var/www/project/src/index.js:1 0|src      | import React from 'react'; 0|src      | ^^^^^^ 0|src      | 0|src` but the rest still there, and there is actually new error ` SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
`

Comment: convert .js files to .mjs OR else instead of import do require to load the module in js file